# Flash animation or Sprite sheet animation good for Unity mobile games

Tags: unity, animation, performance, flash

I would like to develop dress-up and cooking kind of games. So it needs lots of animations. Our designers done the animations in the lash. I found the plugins callued GAF and UniSWF to convert flash animation to Unity or We can convert animations into sprite-sheets and animate them in Unity, But i don't know which one is the best way to do animations for mobiles with better performance and lower game size.

Any kind of suggestion is good. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some tips:

- Try to minimize sprite sizes.
- Try to minimize number of sprites.
- Keep Spritesheet size to less than 8192x8192, as Unity does not support larger than that.

Keep tracking smooth animations as you can get in minimum number and size of frames.

Comment: Thanks for your tips but, how about converting flash animations to Unity with GAF. Is it good or Bad.

Comment: Not that bad, you can use it. But after converting please keep in mind these points. Means if you can downsize Do it! If you can decrease frames Do It!

Comment: A few other considerations for the mobile platform: minimize draw calls (see the profiler).  For mobile I've been told that this number should be as close to 1 as possible.  By which I mean, "under ten, ideally under 3."  Every new shader, every shader option, ever camera, every light increases draw calls, it is not hard to go over 300.  The more draw calls, the more the engine has to add in extra overhead.  Use 1 light, use shaders that use only a single texture, with as few options as possible (mobile shaders typically do not even have a color multiplier).  Combine meshes where possible.

Comment: Thanks friends now i decided to use sprites only. Also i think the plugin codes leads to some other run time unexpected problems.